# v-bind v-model or v-bind.sync?

Tags: vue.js

I dont understand what is the difference between `v-bind`, `v-model`and `v-bind.sync`?

Maybe it's too late, but I can't tell the difference between `v-bind.sync`and `v-model` after reading the documentation.

[Sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

[Passing Data to Child Components with Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

[v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

## Example

I have the following component written in Typescript, using "vue-property-decorator". I don't know how I can manage to update the `date` object passed into the component without having to write the event handling myself. If you ask me, it should work with the `v-model` and with the `v-bind.sync` bindings (and respective changes in the markup and decorator).

#### HTML

```
<Datepicker v-model="date"/>
```

#### Typescript

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Model } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({})
export default class Datepicker extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    private label!: string;
    @Model()
    private date!: Date;
    private internalDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
    private menu = false;

    private onDateChanged() {
        const isoDate = this.date.toISOString();
        const newDate =
            this.internalDate + this.date.toISOString().substring(10);
        this.date = new Date(newDate);
    }
}
```

Every time I change the `this.date` object, I get the warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
> whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
> computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
> "date"

Comment: i'm not familiar with typescript, but using v-model is the recommendet way for such things. the warning you are getting might be a completely different thing, could it be that the transpiler has issues and the source is not properly updated or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

In Vue.js, you should not mutate the input `prop` that is passed to you by the component. For example in your case, consider `label` prop. Within your `DatePicker`, you should not have any statement that does something like `this.label = 'Hello! Change Prop!';`.

> TLDR: Do not mutate the prop within your component. Let parent mutate it.

Coming back to your component, you should have a component like this:

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({})
export default class Datepicker extends Vue {

    @Prop()
    private label!: string;

    @Prop()
    private value!: Date;

    private internalDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);

    private previouslyEmittedDate: Date;

    private menu = false;

    @Watch('value')
    public onDatePropChange() {

        // Break infinite one-way recursion
        if (this.value !== this.previouslyEmittedDate) {
            const newDate = new Date(this.internalDate + this.value.toISOString().substring(10));

            this.previouslyEmittedDate = newDate;

            // input events created a sugar coated v-model binding
            this.$emit('input', newDate);
        }
    }
}
```

**As a side note:** I notice some sort of code smell here. On every date change, you are adding some internal date. It will cause infinite one-way binding recursion. `v-model` is to be used for `input` changed by the user and not programatically. `v-model` is just a sugar-coated syntax for the following:

```
<Datepicker :value="date" @input="this.date = $event"/>
```

Finally, avoid `.sync` modifier. It has a different purpose and should be used sparingly.

Comment: Why do you use `@Prop` for `value` and not `@Model`?

Comment: `@Model` feels little magical. And, if we need `v-model`, we try to stick to `@input` and `:value` pair. It is a small step but helps tremendously when building large-scale applications. Everyone has a common vocabulary.